# Why session storage is giving value as null in this case

Tags: jquery

I am setting a value in session storage , but while retriving it i am getting it as null value .

This is my code

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(12, "3");



var data = [
    {
        "item_id": "12",
        "cost": "30"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "13",
        "cost": "30"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "14",
        "cost": "30"
    }
]

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    var item_id = data.item_id;

    var val_sess = sessionStorage.getItem(item_id);

    console.log(val_sess);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orurq7yL/1/

Answer (score 2):

Because "12" and 12 are not the same things. You need to be consistent in your keys.

Comment: ok , could you please let me know  how do i retrieve it in this case

Comment: @PreethiJain use the same data type, either make your key in storage a string or make your id a number

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the correct type:

```
typeof 12   // number
typeof "12" // string
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes for **12** in ***setItem*** function and don't access to data array correctly.

Change the code as seen below.

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("12", "3");
```

...

```
var item_id = data[i].item_id;
```

See updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/orurq7yL/5/)

Comment: Thank you in case , 12 is dynamic , how can i set 12 in quotes     .window.sessionStorage.setItem(vendor_item_id, currentQuantity);

Comment: You need to cast it to string, eg. window.sessionStorage.setItem(vendor_item_id + '', currentQuantity);

Comment: Preethi Jain: Please, consider marking this answer accepted, if you find the solution correct :)